can it hurt to use "in some embodiments" to describe a feature?
Let's suppose that a feature A is required for the invention to work. In other words, it is required for ALL embodiments.
Of course, the patent examiner will have to deduce this fact, as the document does not state this.
Will it hurt to still use the preamble "In some embodiments, feature A exists"?

A preamble to  what?

@GeorgeWhite The preamble to introduce or describe feature A. So if I were to say "In some embodiments, feature A exists", then I am implying that it is an optional feature, it may in fact be required?

I would recommend not using "in some embodiments" at all, irrespective of whether the feature is in all embodiments or only some.
The specification is supposed to be precise. If one says:
In some embodiments, feature A.
In some embodiments, feature B.

It is not at all clear whether A and B are mutually exclusive or can coexist independently. If they are independent, that should be stated so that nobody can argue later that the inventor never contemplated having both together (this is especially true in cases where the inventor first files a provisional without claims that might otherwise have recited the combination of A and B).
I recommend:
In accordance with the first and third embodiments, feature A.
In accordance with the second and third embodiments, feature B.
Further in accordance with the third embodiment,
  <explain how A and B can be made to interoperate if necessary>.


This might be important in the EPO but would not be an issue in the USPTO.

I don't think there is that much difference. In Hyatt v. Dudas, the examiner made a prima facie case by clearly and specifically explaining why applicant’s specification did not support the particular claimed combination of elements, even though applicant’s specification listed each and every element in the claimed combination e.g. "[I]t is not enough that applicant show where each claimed element resides in the earliest filed application but [he] must also provide support for the linkage of the claimed elements creating the embodiment."

From that ruling “ But this case presents a different question in that we are asked to address not whether Hyatt's proposed claims are actually supported by an adequate written description in these applications, but rather whether the PTO must do more than what MPEP § 2163.04(I)(B) provides to establish a prima facie case of lack of written description in this and every other such case.”

Right, that goes to the allocation of the burden of proof. Once the burden of proof shifted to Hyatt, he had no way to overcome the prima facie case. It would have required showing interconnection of the elements in the earlier specification which he didn't have. Use of "in some embodiment" can likely cause the same situation in which there is a valid prima facie case that written description for a particular later claimed combination might be missing and there is no way to produce argument for it. In Hyatt's case he chose to argue against the sufficiency of the prima facie case (and lost).
